What are the advantages of using partial pivoting in Gaussian elimination compared to rounding off in solving systems of equations?

What's the advantage of using partial pivoting (alternative Gaussian elimination)? In this case, I can use it because if I approximate the result x2 to 1, I'll get strange solutions... But... what's the advantage of using it? Because I can also round off keeping few decimal places, right? Truncation error, from what I understood, will only be generated when I make an approximation with few decimal places.
I say this because I solved it by Cramer's rule and compared it with Wolfram, and it gave the same result. I also tested it on my 2 calculators using their internal function to solve systems of equations, and the result matched
